Is it ok to replace image files in the system32 folder with other image files
I want to get custom system icons, to do this i expect you would replace files in the system32 folder. I want to replace the icons on the taskbar with "cooler" ones, so I found them in c:\windows\system32 and I want to create cooler icons and replace the ones in system 32 (keeping the names the same). I know editing the system32 folder can be very dangerous, but I do not believe this will do any harm. If anyone knows for sure please tell me. Also if you know of any software you can use to do this without damaging your computer please also tell me of that. Thanks

This question appears to be inappropriate question for Stack Overflow. Super User is likely a better spot.
